# How Do You Filter and Sort Data in a CollectionView

Tags: maui

I have a CollectionView on a page that is displaying data from a List<> of items.  I do sorting and filtering in a code behind on the page by changing the List with LINQ, and then setting the BindingContext of the view, like this:

```
MyView.BindingContext = FilteredData;
```

On IOS this works fine, every time, no problem.  On Android, I can change the data a few times (it varies - normally three to five) and then the page doesn't display any data.  In the debugger I can check and still see the ItemsSource has all of the items, but nothing is displayed.  I then "switch" to my other view on the page, which is done by hiding one DataGrid row and showing another, then "switching" back.  The data still isn't displayed, but after I do that I can run the code again that does the sorting and filtering and it starts working again - the data is displayed on the page.  Not only that, but after I do that, it works every time from that point forward on Android.

I've spent hours trying every thing I can think of to try and find an event or property or anything that would indicate when this problem occurs so I can try and find a work around for it.  I'm at a complete loss; wondering if there are suggestions for how to capture and/or fix this problem.

Comment: It’s difficult to say based on just one line of code.  Have you tried just modifying the ItemsSource instead of the entire BindingContext?

Comment: Hi Jason, I know what you mean about the code, but I'm not even what additional code I could paste in that would be illuminating, which is part of the problem.  I have tried modifying the ItemsSource and it's the same problem.  I also tried with property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and it's the same behavior.  I understand the difficulty in trying to answer this...I spent the entire day yesterday trying every weird option I could think of, so just hoping for random suggestions at this point.  I'm getting close to just starting to pull features out of the Android version of this app.

Comment: You might try using MainThread when updating the UI.  Otherwise you might look at the Xamarin samples on filtering to compare how they do it

Comment: Thanks Jason, I tried that as well, but same results.  I did just find a combination that worked.  I'll post it as answer but it's just kind of silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a combination that worked to resolve this issue.  I changed the page so that the CollectionView at issue is in the Grid row that has a non-zero (i.e. visible) height when the ContentPage loads.  After doing that, the code works as expected.  Previously, it was in a Grid.Row whose height was set to an absolute 0 when the page loaded, and then the height was changed to a non-zero value when a button was clicked.

FWIW, this is similar to other issues I've seen with MAUI on Android, where the visibility of certain controls as well as the order in which you modify them can interfere with rendering data binding results.

Comment: Answers will be more helpful to others in the future, if they include a relevant snippet of code. Human languages are too imprecise :) Don't get me wrong: its equally good to have the natural language explanation - but much better to have both.

Comment: Thanks Steve, understand what you are saying.  In this particular case, it just didn't seem to be a coding issue...and that was some of the difficulty I was having in even deciding what code to put in my original question.   But I get it, your point is taken.

Answer (score 0):

I solved sorting using a SortedList and made the list items inherit from IComparable, but I don't love the solution because a SortedList is not an ObservableCollection, and because implementing IComparable can be tricky and leaky.